# Android strange exception

Tags: android, exception, android-service

I just start working on a project which I have to upgrade and upload an update in Android Market. For now I'm just testing the application to see and find any bugs so I can fix them (the app is not written by me). So while I was testing, the application crashed and I got really strange exception (for me), which I've never seen before.

Here it is:

```
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96): ANR in com.nimasystems.android.radio
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96): Reason: Executing service 

com.nimasystems.android.radio/com.nimasystems.android.player.service.DRadioPlayerService
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96): Load: 1.78 / 1.52 / 2.5
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96): CPU usage from 6617ms to 37ms ago:
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   s.android.radio: 67% = 62% user + 5% kernel / faults: 13040 minor
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   system_server: 16% = 8% user + 8% kernel / faults: 361 minor
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   akmd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   synaptics_wq: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96):   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-28 18:29:27.008: E/ActivityManager(96): TOTAL: 85% = 70% user + 14% kernel
```

Any suggestions what can cause this kind of exception?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the DRadioPlayerService spawning a thread to do all the work or is it doing something *silly* - like executing a lot of stuff in `#onCreate` or `#onStartCommand`?

Comment: Actually I think that this maybe is the problem, but it's the first day which I'm testing this code and I have to look closer to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANR or application not responding usually happens when something in your code is preventing the UI thred to do its jobs. Any long term jobs or jobs that potentially can block the UI thread have to be execute in an async way. If you want help to debug you have to share a some code

Comment: I'm still trying to learn the code and the structure of application, that's why I didn't share any code, but thanks for the answer. As I guess, it's some kind of threading issue and I'll have to look closer.

Comment: yes it is. Check for poor responsive network connection or writing/loading big chunks of information from file, semaphore or countdownlatch

Answer (score 1):

the service `com.nimasystems.android.player.service.DRadioPlayerService` some method maybe used most time, the service run in the ui thread, so if you want avoid this, try create a new thread to run your wasted time method.